# Query two unbalanced tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

Sum across two tables returns unwanted Sum from one table multiplied by the number of rows in the other

I have 1 table with Actual results recorded by date and the other tables contains planned results recorded by month.

```
Table 1(Actual)

Date        Location   Amount
01/01/2019  Loc1       1000 
01/02/2019  Loc1       700
01/01/2019  Loc2       7500
01/02/2019  Loc2       1000
02/01/2019  Loc1       500

Table 2(Plan)

Year   Month       Location   Amount
2019   1           Loc1       1500
2019   1           Loc2       8000
2019   2           Loc1       800
```

I have tried various differed Joins using YEAR(Table1.date) and Month(table1.date) and grouping by
Month(Table1.Date) but I keep running into the same problem where the PlanAmount is multiplied by however many rows in the Actual table...

in the example of loc1 for Month 1 below I get

```
Year Month Location PlanAmount  ActualAmount
2019 1     Loc1     3000        1700
```

I would like to return the below

```
Year Month Location PlanAmount  ActualAmount
2019 1     Loc1     1500        1700
2019 1     Loc2     8000        8500
2019 2     Loc1     800         500
```

Thanks in advance for any help
D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `full join` or `union all`/`group by`:

```
select yyyy, mm, location,
       sum(actual_amount) as actual_amount,
       sum(plan_amount) as plan_amount
from ((select year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm, location,
              amount as actual_amount, 0 as plan_amount
       from actual
       group by year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm, location
      ) union all
      (select year, month, location,
              0 as actual_amount, amount as plan_amount
       from actual
       group by year, month, location
      )
     ) ap
group by yyyy, mm, location;
```

This ensures that you have rows, even when there are no matches in the other table.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this allows for expansion to additional columns from other tables, which I have already tested and is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

To get the required results you need to group the first table on year of date, month of date and location and need to select the columns year, month, location and sum of amount from group after that you need to join that resultant r

```
SELECT 
   plans.year, 
   plans.month, 
   plans.location, 
   plans.plan_amount, 
   grouped_results.actual_amount 
FROM plans 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        datepart(year, date) AS year, 
        datepart(month, date) AS month, 
        location, 
        SUM(amount) AS actual_amount 
    FROM actuals 
    GROUP BY datepart(year, date), datepart(month, date), location
) as grouped_results
ON 
    grouped_results.year = plans.year AND 
    grouped_results.month = plans.month AND 
    grouped_results.location = plans.location
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `sum(PlanTable.Amount)` when grouping. Try using `max(PlanTable.Amount)` instead.

```
select 
    p.Year,
    p.Month,
    p.Location,
    sum(a.Amount) as actual_amount,
    max(p.Amount) as plan_amount
from 
    [Plan] p left join Actual a 
        on year(a.date) = p.year
        and month(a.date) = p.Month 
        and a.Location = p.Location
group by 
    p.year,
    p.month,
    p.Location
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f9a41/1/0)

Comment: This worked perfectly and is very similar to some of my own failed attempts, seems I was going round in circles but it is nice to know I was not far away from getting it :)

Answer (score 0):

get year and month from date and use them in join , most dbms has year and month functions you can use according to your DBMS

```
select year(t1.date) yr,month(t1.date) as monthofyr ,t1.Location,
sum(t1.amount) as actual_amoun,
sum(t2.amount) as planamount
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on
month(t1.date)= t2.Month and t1.Location=t2.Location
and year(t1.date)=t2.year
group by year(t1.date) ,month(t1.date),Location
```